# Can't get submit button work

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, phpmyadmin

I am new to java and trying to learn how to add data into database.

I cannot make my submit button work. I am getting error of "target unreachable". I am using hibernate and phpMyAdmin.
As I said I new to this. Please let me know if I am missing information that needed.
Instead of calling class in my submit button should I create private String method for the text boxes?
I am confused.
Thanks a lot for your help.

**additem.xhtml**

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="template.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="content">
            <h1>Add a New Item</h1>


            <br />
            <h:form>
            <p:panel id="panel" header="Enter an Item" style="margin-bottom:20px;"> 
                <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="false" />
                <h:outputLabel value="Item Number" />Item Number: 
                <p:inputText value="#{LibraryItem.itemNumber}" />
                <br />
                <h:outputLabel value="Title" />Title: 
                <p:inputText value="#{LibraryItem.title}" />
                <br />
                <h:outputLabel for="type" value="Type">Item Type: 
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{libraryItem.type}" style="width:228px">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Select One" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="book" itemLabel="Book" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="magazine" itemLabel="Magazine" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="movie" itemLabel="Movie" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="music" itemLabel="Music" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </h:outputLabel>
                <br />
                <h:outputLabel value="Status" />Status: 
                <p:inputText value="#{LibraryItem.status}" />
                <br />
                <p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{AddLibraryItem.addItem}" update="growl" />
                <br />
</p:panel>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>

</html>
```

**AddLibraryItem.java**

```
@Named
@ManagedBean
@Scope("request")
public class AddLibraryItem  {

    //no arg constructor 
    public AddLibraryItem(){

    }


    @Inject private LibraryItem libraryItem;
    @Inject private ILibraryService libraryService;


    public String addItem(){

        //return value
        String returnValue = "success";

        //assign values
        libraryItem.setStatus("CHECKED_IN");

        //add to library
        try {
        libraryService.add(libraryItem);

        displayMessage("Success","Item added");
        }catch (Exception e){
            displayMessage("Error", e.toString());
            return "fail";
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    //Getters and Setters
    public LibraryItem getLibraryItem() {
        return libraryItem;
    }

    public void setLibraryItem(LibraryItem libraryItem) {
        this.libraryItem = libraryItem;
    }

    public ILibraryService getLibraryService() {
        return libraryService;
    }

    public void setLibraryService(ILibraryService libraryService) {
        this.libraryService = libraryService;
    }

    //method to display messages
    private void displayMessage(String title, String message){
        //get faces context
        FacesContext currentInstance = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        //message to show
        FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, title, message);
        //display the message
        currentInstance.addMessage(null, fm);
    }

}
```

Comment: When you say submit button does not work, what does that mean? Do you get any error? Exceptions?

Comment: Sorry yeah I forgot to write "target unreachable" error.

Comment: You have a typo in your `select` tag. Isn't that supposed to be `LibraryItem`?

Comment: I am using primefaces select tag.